# GUI Libraries (python or C++ based) for Engineering Software?

Tags: open-source, python, c++, user-interface, fortran

Background:

I have some engineering software that I am looking to update/modernize by constructing a GUI for user interaction in lieu of command line/input file.

The software is written in Fortran and might be bumped to C++ in the near future. I am familiar with both of these languages plus Python.

I have done a fair amount of research on GUI libraries (QT vs wxWidgets vs TCK vs JavaFX vs .NET) and would like to stick with the main GUI libraries that are: open-source AND python or C++ based.

Question:

What open source GUI library has the ability to create a GUI where I can have a tool bar with engineering elements, drag them to a canvas thereby creating unique instances of an element, connecting the elements, and then defining properties for each element?

The interface I am describing is typical to engineering software and expertly done in the open-source software [DWSIM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dwsim/) or Bentley Haestad products (see image of the latter below, they both use .NET for their GUIs).
[image: Screenshot of Bentley Engineering Software]

Short and simple: CAN wxWidgets, QT or any other C++/python based GUI library be used to create an engineering style interface similar to that shown above?

Comment: You mentioned JavaFX, but then you mention only Python/C++: Have you ruled out Java GUI libraries. Java-based tools such as Pentaho Data Integration and Activiti designer look very much like your screenshot (not sure what libraries they are using but they are open source).